# Ports Showing Closed/Filtered in Nmap Scans

Tags: firewalls, nmap, ports, port-knocking

hopefully this isn't a stupid question.. I am running some nmap scans and I get a list of ports that show closed. Why would they even show in the scan report? Can these be exploited further with other nmap switches such as zombie scans etc? I specified all ports in my scan using -p- .My thought is that it would show a large list of all closed ports on my system not just those?

Here is the command I ran: `nmap -iL axisips.txt -A -sV -p- > axisnmapresults2.txt`

`Host is up (0.062s latency).
Not shown: 65525 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE      VERSION
17/tcp  closed qotd
19/tcp  closed chargen
25/tcp  closed smtp
111/tcp closed rpcbind
136/tcp closed profile
137/tcp closed netbios-ns
138/tcp closed netbios-dgm
139/tcp closed netbios-ssn
443/tcp open   ssl/http     Microsoft HTTPAPI httpd 2.0 (SSDP/UPnP)
|_http-server-header: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`

Comment: what were the port nos?

Comment: Added in Original post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid 65K+ lines of mostly-useless output, Nmap collapses most "uninteresting" results into a line that says something like "Not shown: 65530 filtered ports." Open ports are never collapsed this way, but closed (TCP RST) and filtered (no response or ICMP admin-prohibited) ports are only shown if there are fewer than a certain number.

In your case, I would guess that most of the ports are "filtered" but a few are "closed" instead. There are many reasons this might be the case, but the most likely are:

1. Something between you and the target is blocking access to those ports by spoofing RST replies. This is common with residential ISPs blocking ports 137, 139, and 445, among others.
2. The target's firewall is allowing those ports, but there is no service running on them.

EDITED TO ADD: Based on the actual port output, I'm pretty sure this is ISP filtering (spoofing closed-port responses). Ports 17 and 19 are commonly used as DDoS amplifiers (though UDP, not TCP). Ports 137-139 and 445 have been exploited on Windows by network worms. Port 25 is for email servers, so ISPs block it unless you buy a business-class connection. I'm not sure about 111 and 136; those could be legitimately closed, or they could be blocked for some other reason. Add the `--reason` option to your scan to see details about IP Time-to-Live (TTL) in the response; abnormally high TTL values can indicate ISP blocking, especially if the TTL value for open ports is several hops lower (usually between 5 and 15 hops different or so).

Comment: So just because its showing closed it means its not running but available?

Comment: @john_zombie Basically yes. A "port" is just an address, a number on a packet. A process on a machine can "listen" on the port, which means it tells the OS, "when a connection comes in with this port number, give it to me." When that happens, the port is "open." If no process has asked for a particular number, then a probe to that port will be rejected ("closed"). The firewall inspects connections before any of this and may drop or reject connections regardless of whether a process wants them. So "filtered" means "could be open or closed, but you can't use it anyway."

Comment: So not much I can really do with these ports then? Would it be best practice to hide them from scans?